# Apache type-map only serving uncompressed or only compressed file?

Tags: apache, content-encoding

I want to serve a large (binary but compressible) file using either gzip content encoding or no content encoding (as a fall-back). I thought it should be possible to do this using a type-map. I thus set `AddEncoding x-gzip .gzc` and `AddHandler type-map var .var`. I then created `resource`, `resource.gzc` and `resource.var`. However, I could not get Apache to serve the compressed resource, so I renamed `resource` to `resource.org` and adjusted my type-map accordingly. Now Apache will in fact serve the compressed resource, but not the uncompressed one...

I am testing using `curl -I http://...` (and with `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'` if I want the compressed version).

My type-map now looks like this:

```
URI: resource.org

URI: resource.gzc
Content-Encoding: x-gzip
```

Is my setup wrong? (If so, how do I fix it?) Or is my test wrong? (If so, how should I test my setup?)